# Angular decode the request url

Tags: angular

```js
post<T>(url: string, body: any): Observable<T> { 
    return this.http.post<T>(this.baseUrl + decodeURIComponent(url), body);
}

add(data){
    return this.commonHttpService.post(`/organisations​/add`,data);
}

onSubmit() {
    const controls = this.addForm.controls;
    const data = {
        name: controls.value
    };
    this.homeService
    .add(data)
    .pipe(catchError(err => of(err)
    ), tap((resp: any) => {
    if (resp.status_code === 200) {
        Swal.fire('Ensemble added successfully!', '', 'success') }
```

Request URL I recieved- http://X.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/organisations%E2%80%8B/add

Expected Request URL- http://X.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/organisations/add

I added the decodeURIComponent to the url but still I am getting this request url.
How can we solve this? Tried many ways.

Comment: Create custom function.

Comment: Have you tried with [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#url)?
`ActivatedRoute` have an url property that return an `UrlSegment[] Observable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be out of luck. I copy/paste your code in the javascript console and it showed me an invisible character.

[image: The code constains an invisible dot between organistations and "/add"]

Try to rewrite your code by hand

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I have been on it for hours. You saved me.